# Tomcat Work Directory with Grails Application

Tags: tomcat, grails, tomcat7, grails-2.2, grails-resources-plugin

I have a Grails application (v. 2.2.5) deployed in a production environment. I had some issues with a dashboard page with several graphs loading the data via AJAX. Most of the graphs show up correctly but after a week or so of it being deployed some of the graph's disappear. If I clear out tomcat's work directory, and restart all the graphs show again. How is the cache getting messed up?

-EDIT-
Using the Grails Resources Plugin for compressing and bundling resources.

Comment: love questions of such kind :) what do the log files say?

Comment: Logs say absolutely nothing, the only thing that changes is the JavaScript console which throws an error on a minified resources file (using the Resources plugin)